# Rigging character, mesh not following bones

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, parent, pose-mode

I'm following this tutorial trying to rig my character https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDlJx3J5HX0&ab_channel=KeelanJon but when I switch to pose mode the mesh won't follow the rig when I try to rotate or move it (I have parented the mesh with the rig using automatic weights). It's my first time rigging an character and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Yh7wemHduiglJRc_UBuAtwaXgKNjEolV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Try clicking the mesh first then the rig when parenting with automatic weights

Comment: That's what I've been doing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your ears are very dense and make the parenting fail, so you should simplify them. More genarally your whole mesh is way too dense, especially ears, eyes and hands. You should avoid that, high-poly meshes make any edit and animation very tedious, and if you use a *Subdivision Surface* modifier it makes it even more useless. So rework your mesh before parenting.

Also you have 2 *Subdivision Surface* modifiers, keep one only, give it a level of 2 but disable it until you have a good mesh.

And don't forget to apply the scale of the armature and mesh.

[image]