# What is wrong with my rigging here?

Tags: rigging, armature, parent

For those who monitored questions in this site, I read this one: [Rigging character, mesh not following bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201036/rigging-character-mesh-not-following-bones)
I doesnt solve my problem. Many similar question posted on the internet doesnt solve the problem.

I cant rig my character here, I followed the tutorial from the official blender channel in here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZ3o5tjO51s&list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6&index=30

I did exactly what he did, go to object, select mesh, select armature, ctrl p, with automatic weight

in pose mode, the mesh wont follow the bones

Also edit mode is sometimes inaccessible, for some reason

here is my file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/fw7ppz5aewtcj4b/failed_rigging.blend/file

Answer (score 1):

The blend file already contains the enough instances of mesh object and the armature (RIG-Sky), but the instances are not registered to any scene collection. Therefore delete armature and empty(GRP-Sky) objects and then run the following script to link the instances to a collection.

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    if obj.name not in bpy.context.scene.objects.keys():
        bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(obj)
```

[image]

---

Another way: Use <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> key in the outliner

[image]

Comment: is that the only way to fix it?

Comment: so basically just select all the mesh and press Shift + M???

Answer (score 0):

So Tetit gave a good idea, take a look into the *Outliner > Blend File*, you'll find all the "Geo" objects, put them into a collection, called for example *Character*. Then back into the *Outliner* in *View Layer* mode, select all the objects of *Character* and depending on what you want to do, you could join them all then parent to the armature.

Comment: I'm having a headache now

Comment: So now the character is in pieces after doing what you told me, now what do i have to do?

Comment: Also in the video tutorial, could you help me find the exact same character model that the video used?

Comment: hello, i've re-edited, I hope it helps

Comment: sorry, I cannot find Apply Scale in this part : then CtrlA > Apply Scale

Comment: heellooo? anybody there?

Comment: hello, I've edited my answer, follow Tetit's answer, then, afterwards, it all depends on what you want to do with your armature, do you have actions that you want to use, etc? Maybe precise your demand

Comment: i literally said "i cant rig my characters here" right there in my post above